# React Post Datetime with Timezone

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net, postgresql, react-native

I have a .NetCore Web API. And in this API i am storing some datetime. I am using PostgreSQL. The datetime format looks like this in the database. However, when I want to post data from react, the datetime format is not what I want, so I get an error.

[image]

```
const [name, setName] = useState("");
const [explanation, setExplanation] = useState("");
const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(new Date());const postData = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    axios
        .post(url, {
            name,
            explanation,
            startDate,
            endDate,
        })
        .then((res) => {
            console.log("Posting data :", res);
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-globals
            //history.push("/*");
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
             <input
                                type="datetime-local"
                                id="startDate"
                                name="startDate"
                                onChange={(e) =>
                                    setStartDate(e.target.value)
                                }
                                placeholder="Put in your project start date."
                            />
```

I want the datetime format that I'm trying to post from React look like this. 2022-07-22 16:46:06,505+03. How do I need to control the datetime format with React.

When i post new data its look like this.
[image]

Comment: First, that's not a valid ISO8601 string. Second, Javascript wouldn't generate `2022-07-22 16:46:06,505+03` from a `Date`. Did you store a manually constructed string instead of a `Date` in `startDate` or `endDate` ? If you open your browser's dev tools and type `(new Date()).toISOString();` you'll see that only dots are used, not commas

Comment: What's the *actual* payload sent when you make that call? Open the Network tab in the browser dev tools and inspect the request. Post it in the question itself

Comment: You'll have to parse the DateTime object in the Web API controller (if it's not already doing it for you) and when you pass the DateTime to PostgreSQL, use a string format that the DB engine understands. See [DateTime Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I post it.

Comment: You should be using UTC on your database times. And then present this UTC time in the local timezone of the user, or the local timezone of the origin of the datum (the most relevant to your use case)

Comment: @PabloRecalde quite the opposite. Removing the offset loses important information. That's not the problem here though.

Comment: @Hiedrass the payload contains times without any offset. Not `2022-07-22 16:46:06,505+03.` Dates in PostgreSQL and almost every other database except SQLite have no format, they're binary values. What is the *actual* problem here? What error do you get?

Comment: I'm not saying you should not store the original timezone if relevant, that's why I mention the local timezone of the origin of the datum. But to manage the actual moment in a database, is easier to have a linear UTC rather than a DST changing moment. If you want to know the local time just save its timezone and convert it when representing it. Timestamp with timezone basically means you will have duplicated values on DST changes. Oh nevermind, looks like postgres does the conversion to utc internally for you, and get this.. if you don't specify tz it assumes the database local one. GG

Comment: @Hiedrass and *please* don't post images. Images can't be copied, googled or tested. `2022-07-29T18:26` is a perfectly fine *local* time. What does your .NET code and DTO look like? Unless you convert that value to a `DateTimeOffset` before saving it will be converted to the local timezone automatically

Comment: @PabloRecalde no it's not. If the database type contains an offset, it should be the actual offset, not the time converted to UTC. And no, it doesn't mean DST gets duplicated, quite the opposite. Using UTC means you have no idea if DST was applied or not and won't be able to convert to the correct local time. Having an offset isn't as good as having an IANA timezone name, but it's far better than UTC

Comment: @PabloRecalde assuming UTC is a panacea has many entries in the [Falsehoods programmers believe about time](https://gist.github.com/timvisee/fcda9bbdff88d45cc9061606b4b923ca)

Comment: I mean, postgres `timestamp with timezone` is actually converting it to UTC... look it up on the documentation :) That link is just what some freelancer from the netherlands has read on some other blog post by someone else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246675/discussion-between-pablo-recalde-and-panagiotis-kanavos).